# Removing Gnome3-session properly

Tags: gnome

I attempted to install Gnome3 in my Ubuntu 11 and got busted . And i reinstalled Ubuntu  and attempted again to install Gnome3 . Now when i installed the Gnome3-session ,  weird things are happening -

- No packages are able to install -

  The Error : ( when i issued "sudo apt-get install openssh-server" )

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    gnome-session : Depends: gnome-session-bin (< 2.33) but 3.0.1-0ubuntu1~build2 is to be installed
>                    Depends: gnome-session-common (= 2.32.1-0ubuntu20) but 3.0.1-0ubuntu1~build2 is to be installed

- Ubuntu software center is asking to repair the repository

So i've the fear , that if i log out , i may not be able to log-in again ( which happened earlier )

How to remove / fix this condition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That will try to fix the unmet dependencies.

Comment: wow , that worked like  charm . I'm able to install anything . So that gnome3-session won't affect anything anymore ?

Comment: from where did you get gnome 3? the ppa? or did you compile it?

Comment: hopefully :) if the answer works for you, please mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @Uri Herrera , i installed it via apt-get .

Comment: Well , what i feared has occurred to me - i can't log in . Messed up........